# how to load models (ecores) which are referenced in my model programmatically

Tags: emf, xmi

I'm working on a tool to transform a model to MetaModel programmatically, and I figure out with this problem:
when I load/save a Model 'A' (xmi) that contain EClass with superType referencing others Classifier in other ecores 'B', 'C' ( separated ecores files), I got null for each cross References.

How to load Ecore if my model contain a cross reference to it ? use nsUri ?